# How to make a column of numbers increase from a certain value in python

Tags: python

I have a txt file like this:

```
127 181
151 188
120 201
148 207
148 212
145 215
86 219
108 219
67 239
```

And I want to the second column of numbers is added in order from 180, and the repeated number is added only once.
My expected results are as follows:

```
127 180
151 181
120 182
148 183
148 184
145 185
86 186
108 186
67 187
```

Can someone give me some advice?Thanks.

Comment: I don't see any `182` in your first `dataset`.

Comment: Ok, are you open to use a library like pandas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are open to use pandas:

```
df = pd.read_csv('textfile.txt', header=None, sep=' ')

startvalue = 180
df[1] = np.arange(startvalue, startvalue+len(df)) - df[1].duplicated().cumsum()

df.to_csv('textfile_out.txt', sep=' ', index=False, header=False)
```

Full example (with imports and textfile-creation):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

with open('textfile.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('''\
127 181
151 188
120 201
148 207
148 212
145 215
86 219
108 219
67 239''')

df = pd.read_csv('textfile.txt', header=None, sep=' ')
startvalue = 180
df[1] = np.arange(startvalue, startvalue+len(df)) - df[1].duplicated().cumsum()

df.to_csv('textfile_out.txt', sep=' ', index=False, header=False)
```

Output:

```
127 180
151 181
120 182
148 183
148 184
145 185
86 186
108 186
67 187
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using any library, I suggest this approach. Create a dictionary to store the relation (old value - new value) and iterate over column values.

```
n = 180
new_dict = {}

for index, value in enumerate(column):
    if value in new_dict.keys():
        column[index] = new_dict[value]
    else:
        new_dict[value] = n
        column[index] = n
        n += 1
```